# How do I delete columns that contain a zeros value in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to retain only non zero columns

df:

```
Names        Henry    Adam   Rachel  Jug   Jesscia
Robert         54      0        0     6       5
Dan            22      31       0     0       55
```

Expected output:

```
Names        Henry         Jesscia
Robert         54              5
Dan            22             55
```

```
df.loc[:, (df != 0).any(axis=0)]
did not remove the columns with only one zero value
```

Comment: If you want a non-pandas way to do it, upload the contents of your raw csv.

Comment: You were so close! Just `all` vs `any`. You wanted columns were _all_ values were not equal to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
df.loc[:,~df.eq(0).any()]
```

OR

as suggested by [`@sammywemmy`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7175713/sammywemmy)

```
df.loc[:, df.ne(0).all()]
```

Other possible solutions:

```
df.mask(df.eq(0)).dropna(axis=1)
#OR
df.drop(df.columns[df.eq(0).any()],1)
```

output of above code:

```
    Names  Henry  Jesscia
0  Robert     54        5
1     Dan     22       55
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[:, df.eq(0).sum().eq(0)]
```

or:

```
    df.where(df.ne(0)).dropna(1)
```

```
    Names   Henry   Jesscia
0   Robert  54      5
1   Dan     22      55
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following:

```py
df.replace(0, np.nan).dropna(how='any', axis=1)
```